# Object reference not set to an instance of an object. This happens while adding checkboxlist control dynamically

Tags: asp.net

**Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**

```
protected void cmdSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string strNames = string.Empty;
    CheckBoxList Chkboxx = (CheckBoxList)PlaceHolder1.FindControl("Chkbox");
    foreach (ListItem em in Chkboxx.Items)  //-------- (Showing error)
    {
        if (em.Selected)
        {
            strNames += em.Value + ", ";
        }
    }

    string final_name = strNames.Substring(0, strNames.Length - 2);
    lblNames.Text = final_name;

}
```

**Actually I am adding Checkbox control dynamically :**

```
protected void ddl_varient_SelectedIndexChanged1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string query = "select prd_vrtyvalue_id,varient_value from tbl_ProductVariety_Value  where varient='" + ddl_varient.SelectedItem.Text + "' " +
                      " order by varient_value asc ";
    DataTable abc = new DataTable();
    SqlDataAdapter ada = new SqlDataAdapter(query, new CommonClass().connection());
    ada.Fill(abc);

    ChkboxList.ID = "Chkbox";
    for (int i = 0; i < abc.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        ChkboxList.Items.Add(new ListItem(abc.Rows[i]["varient_value"].ToString(), abc.Rows[i]["prd_vrtyvalue_id"].ToString()));
    }
    ChkboxList.RepeatColumns = 2; 
    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(ChkboxList);
}
```

***Can Anybody tell me, what exactly i am doing wrong !***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way ASP.NET WebForms work is that the entire page is re-built during each post back. So, I imagine this is what is occuring:

- Page gets "built" and includes only controls defined within your ASCX/ASPX file.
- User clicks on DDL_VARIENT checkbox and the ChkboxList is added to PlaceHolder1
- Form is rendered back to the user so they can see ChkboxList
- Save button is clicked, causing another postback.
- Page is re-built, setting all the controls back to what is defined within your ASPX/ASCX code. This does **not** include ChkboxList.
- Your code is hit, ChkboxList no longer exists and you get your problem.

To fix, you could re-add your ChkboxList on Page_Load depending on the value of your DDL_VARIENT checkbox. If I were you though, I'd be tempted to define the ChkboxList within your ASPX/ASCX code and then set the visibility of the list depending on the value of the DDL_VARIENT checkbox within Page_Load.

I should add, the entire of the above is dependant upon you using ASP.NET WebForms. If you're using MVC then it's probably wrong.